# How to make a test dir?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to set up a basic hello world project. The unit tests should be in the `test/` directory as described in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/testing.html). My code so far is as follows.

**src/main.rs**

```
pub mod player;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

**src/player.rs**

```
pub fn rep(arg: i32) -> i32 {
    arg
}
```

**tests/player.rs**

```
extern crate player;

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    assert_eq!(4, player::rep(2+2));
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "myapp"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["My Name <spam@example.com>"]
```

I believe the code is very similar to the book. However, `cargo test` fails:

```
tests/player.rs:1:1: 1:21 error: can't find crate for `player`
tests/player.rs:1 extern crate player;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

What is the problem? I'm completely lost.

Comment: You might want to add the contents of your `Cargo.toml` file; that determines the name of things, which is probably where your issue is.

Comment: @DK. please, take a look at my edit with `Cargo.toml`. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems.  First of all, you're building an executable, not a library, so you can't link against the result to test it.  Secondly, you appear to be confused as to the difference between modules and crates.  You might want to read the [Crates and Modules chapter of the Rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html).

If you want types and methods from your crate to be externally accessible, you need to compile your code into a library.  Often, executables in Rust will just be thin wrappers around a library of the same name.  So, you might have:

```rust
// src/main.rs
extern crate player;

fn main() {
    println!("rep(42): {:?}", player::rep(42));
}
```

```
// src/lib.rs
pub fn rep(arg: i32) -> i32 { arg }
```

This would allow you to test `player::rep`.

The other thing you can do is just write the test next to the code it's testing.

```
// src/lib.rs
pub fn rep(arg: i32) -> i32 { arg }

#[test]
fn test_rep() { assert_eq!(rep(4), 4); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling a binary instead of a library (crate). Try renaming "main.rs" to "lib.rs".

Comment: oh, but I intend to make a binary, the result of this project should be an executable file...

Comment: Tests directories are used to test function APIs of libraries. Since binaries don't have those, it doesn't really make sense to use test directories in that case. You want to use internal test modules for testing binaries.